# CSS only Image with thumbnails popup

Tags: html, css, image, popup

I need a CSS only solution that enables images when clicked on to enlarge on the same page with a popup box and faded out background.

I have the main layout setup with a main image and then thumbnails underneath this. When the user clicks on either the main image or any of the thumbnails I want the pop up box to display showing a larger image size.

Then when the user clicks on the images and the popup appears I need a cross in the corner which then closes the popup box.

This is an example: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/352338537173?ViewItem=&item=352338537173

Although the example above also changes the thumbnails to the main image which I don't want. So a simpler version of this in that when the thumbnail images are clicked they will just enlarge the same as the main image would.

The main layout of the code I have done so far is as follows:

CSS

```
#images {
width: 100%%;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 500px;
}
#main-image {
width: 100%;
}
#main-image img { 
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
#thumbnail-images {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
overflow: auto;
padding: 15px 0;
}
#thumbnail-images ul {
float: left;
margin-bottom: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
}
#thumbnail-images li {
width: 20%;
margin: 7px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
display: block;
}
#thumbnail-images li img {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="images">
<div id="main-image"><a href="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/673111786_960.jpg"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/673111786_960.jpg" /></a></div>
<div id="thumbnail-images">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/673111786_960.jpg"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/673111786_960.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/673111786_960.jpg"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/673111786_960.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/673111786_960.jpg"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/673111786_960.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/673111786_960.jpg"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/673111786_960.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a modal-popup?  Please see if this example is what you are looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp . If so I could provide an appropriate answer for your situation.

Comment: @user2796515 Yes similar to that and also https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp. But it has to be only CSS so no javascript etc. This example https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/352338537173?ViewItem=&item=352338537173 does it without javascript and I want it similar to this but I don't need the thumbnails to update to the main image. When the thumbnails are clicked on I just want them to pop up into the larger image straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Look on this. Hope it helps you.

```css
 #gallery {
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 100px auto;
    border: 2px solid #003C72;
  }
  #navigation {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
  }
  #navigation li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
  }
  #navigation li a img {
    display: block;
    border: none;
  }
  #navigation li a {
    display: block;
  }
  #full-picture {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
  }
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
 <ul id="navigation">
 <li><a href="#pic1"><img alt="" src="https://basicuse.net//content/download/1422/6814/file/nature1.jpg" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#pic2"><img alt="" src="https://basicuse.net//content/download/1423/6816/file/nature2.jpg" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#pic3"><img alt="" src="https://basicuse.net//content/download/1424/6818/file/nature3.jpg" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#pic4"><img alt="" src="https://basicuse.net//content/download/1425/6820/file/nature4.jpg" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#pic5"><img alt="" src="https://basicuse.net//content/download/1426/6822/file/nature5.jpg" /></a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="full-picture">
 <div><a name="pic1"></a><img alt="" src="https://basicuse.net//content/download/1413/6796/file/nature1.jpg" /></div>
 <div><a name="pic2"></a><img alt="" src="https://basicuse.net//content/download/1414/6798/file/nature2.jpg" /></div>
 <div><a name="pic3"></a><img alt="" src="https://basicuse.net//content/download/1416/6802/file/nature3.jpg" /></div>
 <div><a name="pic4"></a><img alt="" src="https://basicuse.net//content/download/1417/6804/file/nature4.jpg" /></div>
 <div><a name="pic5"></a><img alt="" src="https://basicuse.net//content/download/1418/6806/file/nature5.jpg" /></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but this isn't quite what I was looking for.